# Finding the major and minor axises of an Ellipse knowing a certain point P and its eccentricity?

Tags: math, ellipse

In a project I'm working on the user creates a circle and choose a point on that circle, P=(px,py). For the question's sake, let's assume the center of the circle is at (0,0).

After the previous steps, the user can then change the eccentricity of the ellipse (as it was a circle it was actually an ellipse with e=0). While he changes the eccentricity, the ellipse should keep its center to (0,0), and the point P should stay on the ellipse's circumference.

Thanks!
Aviad.

Comment: This isn't a programming question!

Comment: True. But I've seen a few mathematical questions laying around and figured it's okay to ask it...

Comment: Suggest http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @Donnie: This question would be quickly closed on mathoverflow -- it's way too elementary for their audience of professional mathematicians.

Comment: @Donnie : no, this is NOT for  mathoverflow.net

Comment: Ah, nevermind then.  I didn't realize they closed the simple stuff so easily / rapidly.  Understandable I guess if their target audience is professional mathematicians.

Comment: Posted it there as well. I guess I'll be ridiculed. But - can you guys just vote it up then and answer ?? :-)

Comment: When/if it materializes, this belongs on the site proposed in http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355

Comment: @donroby: Indeed. Is there a way I can add it to the example questions?

Comment: Perhaps you should reconsider the representation you are using for the ellipse; rather than storing its eccentricity and a point on it, just store the semi-major axis lengths and the angle by which it is tilted. This is probably more numerically robust.

Comment: @Aviad: Apparently example questions can only be added during the definition phase in area51.  It might be good to add this once it goes beta, even though it's been answered here instead of closed like alot of math questions.

Comment: @Victor: The problem is I don't know the major axis - part of the problem is to find it, using only the eccentricity (which I set), and two points - the center point and an arbitrary point in the origin circle's perimeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I made no mistake, the half axis of the ellipse are a = sqrt(x²+y²/(1-e²)) and b = a * sqrt(1-e²)

For the numeric eccentricity we have:

I) b = a * sqrt(1-e²)

and the equation for a point on the ellipse is:

II) x²/a² + y²/b² = 1

Substitue I) in II)

x²/a² + y²/(a² * (1-e²)) = 1

1/a² (x² + y²/(1-e²)) = 1

a² = (x² + y²/(1-e²))

a = sqrt(x² + y²/(1-e²))

Comment: x,y in this answer refer to my px, py, right ? i.e. the point in the original circle?

Comment: x and y refer to all points on the ellipse, and of course px, py is one of them :-)